# Is there a way to display the version numbers for each package I have installed into my emacs?

Tags: emacs

The question pretty much says it all. I wish to know which version I have installed. If I look at the directories in my `elpa` folder I just see a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the directory name next to the package name *is* the version of the package. If you are seeing dates, then you have installed packages from a package repository which uses dates as versions. (That would probably be melpa.)

If you want something different, you will need to use a package repository with a saner version policy. melpa-stable is an option.

Answer (score 0):

List all packages available:

M-x package-list-packages

Although you can only filter by keyword, you could use this *workaround* to list only installed packages:

```
(defun installed-packages ()
  (interactive)
  (list-packages t)
  (read-only-mode -1)
  (delete-non-matching-lines " installed   ")
  (read-only-mode 1))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with EL. Is `progn` like the threading macro in clojure?

Comment: `C-h f progn`. (n.b. it's entirely unnecessary in this instance.)

Comment: Correct. `progn` is unnecessary here, because `BODY` forms  of a `defun` are already evaluaetet sequentially. I fixed it.

Comment: `progn` is like clojures `do`

Comment: I don't know of a threading macro in elisp. Someone ? **edit**: a search gave some results, specially I had missed the ones in `dash.el`: https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#threading-macros